# Что означает атрибут crossorigin у элемента img?

Tags: html, html5, запрос, cross-origin

Как я понял атрибут `crossorigin` - для обработки запросов с других источников. 
Перечитал интернет, так толком и не понял смысл атрибута. Он нужен, если я хочу взять и загрузить картинку с чужого сайта на свой сайт? Что мне для этого нужно, в `src` указать адрес этой картинки и использовать атрибут `crossorigin`?
Значения атрибута совсем не понимаю, что означают:

```
anonymous

use-credentials
```

Кто-нибудь может объяснить принцип работы атрибута?

Например, код, почему не отображается картинка с другого сайта? Какое значение нужно добавить в атрибут, чтобы картинка появилась?

```
 <body>
    <div>
        <img src="http://russian7.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/20130215184904.jpg" crossorigin="">
    </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Чем вас не устроило это? https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Answer (score 4):

**crossorigin**
Этот атрибут определяет, используется ли CORS при загрузке изображения. Изображения, [загруженные с помощью CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image), могут использоваться в элементах , не ограничивая функциональность последних (англ. tainted canvas).
У этого атрибута есть 2 допустимых значения:
**anonymous**
В этом случае перед загрузкой изображения выполняется cross-origin запрос (т.е., используется Origin: HTTP header). Однако, при этом не передаются параметры доступа (ни cookie, ни сертификат X.509, ни логин/пароль для базовой аутентификации по HTTP). В ответе сервера должен присутствовать заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin: HTTP header, иначе использование изображения в  ограничивается.
**use-credentials**
Перед загрузкой изображения выполняется cross-origin запрос (Origin: HTTP header) с указанием параметров доступа (в виде cookie, сертификата или пары логин/пароль). В ответе сервера должен присутствовать заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin: HTTP header, иначе использование изображения в  ограничивается.
Если данный атрибут не задан, CORS при загрузке изображения не используется (нет заголовка Origin: HTTP header), и использование изображения в  ограничивается всегда. При неверном значении атрибута (например, при опечатке), используется значение anonymous. Для дополнительной информации обратитесь к статье [CORS settings attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes).
[Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Comment: что-то нифига не понял. Так правильно ли я понимаю, что его можно использовать для того, чтобы загрузить картинку с чужого сайта на свой сайт? Что мне для этого нужно, в src указать адрес этой картинки и использовать атрибут crossorigin?

Comment: Работает, но что если необходимо чтобы сайт с которого подгружаем изображение или указываем url, произвел манипуляции с куками на стороне пользователя. Есть решение,

Answer (score 2):

**crossorigin** нужен, когда ты хочешь подгрузить изображение с чужого сайта для использования его в элементе canvas, что позволяет делать с изображением различные манипуляции. Например библиотека, для создания скришотов в браузере, **html2canvas** не сможет захватить картинки на странице если они лежат на другом сайте, вот тут и может помочь этот атрибут, но ресурс на котором лежат изображения должен передавать и ними заголовок **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**.